# What is a word for an unaffiliated gunfighter in western movies?

Tags: vocabulary, cinema

I'm trying to think of a word for the kind of person in western movies (I mean like "The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly" etc) who is a gunfighter who does not have a group affiliation. The closest I can come is "ronin" but I'm thinking there is an English equivalent and I just haven't thought of it yet.

Some possibilities: drifter, wanderer (doesn't suggest agency or capability of action), gunslinger (doesn't say anything about affiliation), outlaw (lawful or unlawful not immediately relevant here).

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Are you looking for a specifically Western-movie word for that sort of person, or a more generic term that translates the Western-movie trope into other situations?

Comment: @AlexP I'm thinking in terms of western movie vocabulary in particular.

Comment: Sounds rather like The Lone Ranger.

Comment: More like _Have Gun--Will Travel_ than The Lone Ranger

Answer (score 14):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "unaffiliated:"

- A character who will join any side of a conflict for money, like a mercenary, is a **hired gun**.

  - If they're someone who tracks down criminals for money, they're a **bounty hunter** by profession.
- A character without community ties is a loner, wanderer, or **drifter**. (Sometimes the townspeople will call them "**stranger**.")
- A character who lives outside the legal and moral codes of society is an **outlaw** or **desperado**.

  - If you really want to emphasize that they support themselves through criminal activity, especially as part of a gang, they're a **bandit**.
- If you're looking for an analogue for the *principled* ronin, the warrior who was highly devoted to something that doesn't exist anymore, the closest Western trope is probably "the **veteran**" (who could also be a hired gun, drifter, &c.), but be mindful that, because of the history of the genre, it tends to imply that the character was a *Confederate* soldier in the American Civil War, unless specified otherwise.

If you're not sure, I recommend you look up a movie with multiple gunslinger characters, like *[The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_good,_the_bad,_and_the_ugly#Cast)* or *[Magnificent Seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magnificent_Seven#Cast)*, and see how people describe the character that most closely matches the archetype you have in mind.

Comment: "see how people describe the character" = The Blondie. Very minor nitpick: bounty hunters compete for bounties, so they are not generally hired.

Answer (score 6):

**Hired Gun:**

> One, especially a professional killer, who is hired to kill another person.

[American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hired+gun)

Also used currently for any newly added specialist on staff.

Answer (score 3):

The OP should look no further than his own question -- the word is ***gunfighter***.  The iconic unaffiliated hero of Western movies is Shane, and Shane was called a gunfighter.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shane_(film)0):

> Shane (Alan Ladd), a skilled, laconic **gunfighter** with a mysterious
>   past, rides into an isolated valley in the sparsely settled state
>   of Wyoming, some time after the Civil War.  (emphasis added.)

*Shane* was one of the all-time great Western movies. The source linked above says:

> Shane is a 1953 American Technicolor Western film from
>   Paramount, noted for its landscape cinematography, editing,
>   performances, and contributions to the genre. The picture was
>   produced and directed by George Stevens from a screenplay by A. B.
>   Guthrie, Jr., based on the 1949 novel of the same name by Jack
>   Schaefer. Its Oscar-winning cinematography was by Loyal Griggs.
>   Shane stars Alan Ladd, Jean Arthur (in the last feature, and only
>   color, film of her career) and Van Heflin, and features Brandon
>   deWilde, Jack Palance, Emile Meyer, Elisha Cook, Jr., and Ben
>   Johnson.
>
> Shane was listed No. 45 in the 2007 edition of AFI's 100 Years...100
>   Movies list, and No. 3 on AFI's 10 Top 10 in the 'Western' category.

In his [review of *Shane*](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/great-movie-shane-1953), Roger Ebert called Shane a gunfighter:

> Yes, on the surface, Shane is the **gunfighter** who wants to leave his
>   past behind him, who yearns for the sort of domesticity he finds on
>   Joe Starrett's place in the Grand Tetons. Yes, someone has to stand up
>   to the brutal Rufus Ryker (Emile Meyer), who wants to tear down the
>   fences and allow his cattle to roam free. Yes, Shane is the man--even
>   though he knows that if he succeeds he'll have to leave the valley.

Answer (score 1):

***Maverick*** captures the 'unconventional' part, which also implies 'unaffiliated':

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/maverick)

> *noun* : 2a) a person of independent or unorthodox views
>
> Word Origin C19: after Samuel A. Maverick (1803–70), Texas rancher,
>   who did not brand his cattle

(It doesn't say anything about the owner being a gunfighter)